# I have trouble writing a getter for a vector

Tags: c++, vector

Why does `item.someVector.push_back(1);` seem to work, but not `item.getSomeVector().push_back(1);` ?

Here is my test case:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Item {
public:
  vector<int> someVector = vector<int>();
  vector<int> getSomeVector()
  {
    return someVector;
  }
};

int main()
{
  Item item = Item();

  item.getSomeVector().push_back(1);
  cout << item.getSomeVector().size() << endl;
  cout << item.someVector.size() << endl;

  item.someVector.push_back(1);
  cout << item.getSomeVector().size() << endl;
  cout << item.someVector.size() << endl;
}

// output:
// 0
// 0
// 1
// 1
```

Comment: Hmm, they both work fine. It is just a problem with your expectations.

Comment: Your `getSomeVector` returns a vector by value. At a guess, you probably want to return a reference instead.

Comment: Good idea to show what is happening vs. what you expect to happen.

Comment: Please don't do this: `vector<int> someVector = vector<int>();` just do this: `vector<int> someVector;`.

Comment: @Galik I was just about to mention that - this isn't java, so don't write java.

Comment: @Galik: care to elaborate why my (java-influenced) form is discouraged?

Comment: @Zalumon In `Java` all user defined types are accessed by *reference* but primitive types (like `int`) are accessed by value. So in `Java` you say `int i;` not `int i = new int();`. In `C++` you can treat user defined types like built-in types and access them by value *just like* integers. So `MyType myType;` is correct. Doing it the "Java way" causes two objects to be created and then the second object is copied over (or possibly moved into) the first one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `getSomeVector` returns a copy of `someVector`. So you're updating a temporary object which is then immediately destroyed. Try changing it to `vector<int>& getSomeVector()`

Comment: @erip Guess I just hit F5 faster :)

Comment: Heh, 6 upvotes in 3 mins... This will rocket you to 1,000 rep pretty easily ;).

Comment: @KemyLand I guess people are feeling generous on a Sunday morning.

Comment: thanks, I'm obviously struggling with c++ references

Comment: @Zalumon No worries. That's why we're all here: to give people a little help.